# How to process big text file and work on it in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a txt file of near about 2.5gb and i am reading this file

```
text_content = text_file.readlines()
```

the problem is, in return it gives us a list of near about 7.5 million records

```
empty_list=[]
for sentence in text_content :
   if "333" in sentence:
       # do something and append it in empty list
```

This process takes alot of time and memory.
I need to know some easy and fast way to do the same.

Comment: so what I do is add what I want to a CSV file.this way one function can process many Text files.and This way you are storing the data from the text you want. Next you can use pandas to transform your csv anyway yo want in memory ( as the input) then output a new CSV as your output. if you want me to show this solution as your answer I can for the rep

Comment: yeah sure.. please do it @BlackFox

Comment: Us living outside India don't use words like "lakh" or "lac" -- and therefore people have no idea what is a "75 lacs record".

Answer (score 3):

Try this with large text file:

```
with open("name.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if "333" in line:
            # do your stuff here
```